# VCOM Drivers Not Working after Changing PID/VID

Tags: windows, driver, usbserial

I ran into a problem when using Silicon Labs' CP2102 USB-UART bridge controller. Silicon Labs offers an application for changing USB related configuration values (PID,VID,Device Description...) so I changed the VID value to the ones assigned to me by the USB-IF Administration. All fields appear to have been correctly updated (I ca see that in Device Manager) but Windows reports that there are no drivers available. Before changing the VID/PID and device description everything worked well.

Any idea how to tell Windows to use the same drivers as before? Is it possible or perhaps even normal for a driver to be tied to a specific VID/PID and by changing it I basically "broke" the controller unless I write my own drivers?

OS: Windows 7
USB-UART Controller: Silicon Labs CP2102
More information about the controller: http://www.silabs.com/products/interface/usbtouart/Pages/usb-to-uart-bridge.aspx

Thank you in advance for all your help.

Comment: Microsoft of course doesn't know anything about your new VID so cannot recommend a driver.  You'll have to update the INF file and modify the [DeviceList] so it can be installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Driver Customization Wizard (AN220SW](http://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/Software/AN220SW.zip)). If you create a driver with a matching VID and PID as your customized device you can get it to load again (as well as re-customize back to default, or something else). The documentation for this is in [Application Note 220](https://www.silabs.com/Support%20Documents/TechnicalDocs/an220.pdf).

Comment: I can't apologize enough for this unacceptable delay in replying. I really don't know how this slipped my attention. Replying after 10 months is probably frowned upon but for the sake of completeness I want to thank you for your post. It indeed contains the correct answer, which is what I ended up doing in the end. Thanks.